# Seagate Wireless Pro access via File Explorer on Windows

Tags: hard-drive, wifi, seagate

I bought a [Seagate Wireless Pro Harddrive](http://www.seagate.com/consumer/stream/wireless-plus/) and I'm unable to access the network share on some devices but I can access their UI through the browser on all devices.  I used [this](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005098en?language=en_US) as a guide initially.

I'm using company issues laptops that have the full version of Windows 8 and 10 installed on them.  I've been able to connect to the share on a work laptop using Windows 7 and on my home computer that uses Windows 10.

So far I've tried the following:

- Updated the firmware on the device
- Turned off all antivirus applications
- Had IT remove the Group Policy from the 2 devices that wont work.
- Mapping the network drive using the net use command (which worked, but I still can connect to the share).
- Configured the wireless hard drive to accept SAMBA and DNLA
- Tried starting services that dealt with Remote Procedure Call (RDC) according to the error I get below.
- Checked the event log and there are no logs anywhere

The error that I get changes based on the way I try to access the share:

- An unexpected network error occurred
- You may not be authorized or have permission
- The remote procedure call failed and did not execute

Comment: So connecting via WiFi is working as expected, you only have trouble when you try to mount the share, right? Have you set the device back to defaults and experienced the same behavior?

Comment: @sippybear Correct.  I have set the device back to defaults as well using the reset button on the back of the hard drive. (although I believe that only reset the WiFi settings).  Either way, I still cannot mount the share from the Windows 8 or 10 work tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is caused by incompatible versions of CIFS/SMB.

On one of the Win10 systems that fail to connect, please try the following:

1. Run `appwiz.cpl` (The add/remove programs wizard).
2. Click "Turn Windows features on or off"
3. Enable "SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support"

Make sure to close all File Explorer instances, then try to re-connect.

Comment: This feature was already turned on.  I turned it off, tried again after a reboot, turned the feature back on, rebooted and tried again.  Both times it still fails with the same error.